# Changing task_runner in prefect deployment

Tags: python, prefect

Is there a way to change the `task_runner` within a prefect deployment? I would like to have possibility to have for a single flow a deployment with say `ConcurrentTaskRunner` and `DaskTaskRunner` (local or remote).

The only way I have found so far is to create within deployment:

```
infra_overrides:
  env:
    dask_server: True
```

And on the flow level something like:

```
def determine_runner():
    return DaskTaskRunner if os.environ.get("dask_server") == "True" else ConcurrentTaskRunner

@flow(task_runner=determine_runner())
def my_flow():
    pass
```

This works as in normal run I don't have variable `dask_server` and in special deployment run where I set this variable agent starts each run on clean environment with this variable set up. But my guess is that **there must be a better way**. If there was a solution on deployment level I could have a single function [building from flows](https://docs.prefect.io/api-ref/prefect/deployments/#prefect.deployments.Deployment.build_from_flow) instead of adding to each flow a function `determine_runner`.

Of course it would be best if there was possibility to do something like:

```
Deployment.build_from_flow(
...
task_runner=my_preferred_runner,
)
```

Which is not implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add environment variables that determine which task runner gets used. [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/issues/5560#issuecomment-1274800069) has a detailed explanation but here is a TL;DR:

```py
@flow(
    task_runner=DaskTaskRunner()
    if os.environ.get("MY_ENV") == "prod"
    else ConcurrentTaskRunner(),
)
def my_flow():
```